# Add a reference to relate to an Index Match Formula

Tags: excel-formula

QUESTION, How can I add a reference to this Index Match Formula?

- Index Match Formula @ I23, obtains 'Variant Image'.
- This is the Index Match formula used at I23           =INDEX(I4:I18,MATCH(D23&F23&H23,D4:D18&F4:F18&H4:H18,0))'

PROBLEM

- This formula needs a reference to find the options specific to itself @ B23
- If there is no reference , products @ B4 @ B13 cannot be differentiated because their variants are the same

[IMAGE: The Index Match Formula Needs a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASlan.png)

Answer (score 0):

This was very easy to solve, I just added the cell and column I wanted to reference. The answer is,

```
=INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0))
```